# Excel: How to create list of unique elements respect one column?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, sum, formula

I have a list like this (small example):

```
Orig Dest Qty
BEL  PL   12
UK   PL   45
BEL  DNK  32
ESP  DNK  22
UK   CZE  14
BEL  PL   11
UK   PL   31
UK   CZE  08
```

I would like to list it like this:
(Summarize the Qty by each origin-destination combination)

```
Orig Dest Qty
BEL  DNK  32
BEL  PL   23
ESP  DNK  22
UK   CZE  22
UK   PL   76
```

So notice that every single combination is listed, and for each combination, the sum is displayed (alphabetical order is not necessary).

I hope it's possible without using VBA.

Thanks,
Ruben

Comment: What version of excel do you use?

Comment: Maybe `=LET(X,UNIQUE(A2:B9),Y,SORTBY(X,INDEX(X,,1),1,INDEX(X,,2),1),Z,SUMIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,INDEX(Y,,1),B2:B9,INDEX(Y,,2)),CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDEX(Y,,1),INDEX(Y,,2),Z))` works. But maybe just consider a pivot-table?

Answer (score 3):

With `Excel-365` you can try below formulas.

```
E2=UNIQUE(A2:B9)
G2=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,E2,$B$2:$B$9,F2)
```

If you do not have `UNIQUE()` function then it would be hard to get unique list of `Orig` and `Dest` column by formula but still you can use `SUMIFS()` function.

[image]